# Error- "The size (12000) given to the type 'VarChar' exceeds the maximum allowed (8000)" in Azure dataware house

Tags: azure, hadoop, data-warehouse, azure-synapse

I am trying to execute T-SQL in Azure Dataware house and it's not allowing me to have data type greater then varchar(8000), can anyone please suggest some alternative to this.
(Same issue happened on table creation as well , it doesn't support blob or LOB datatype even with Bulk Loading or poly base loading, so i ended up loading trimmed data.)

Comment: You can try VARCHAR(MAX), which will support up to 2GB, but the page size in SQL is still limited to 8,000 so I'm not sure if that will help or not. And Polybase is limited to 1MB per row. Here is another useful SO entry: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57425069/azure-sql-data-warehouse-max-size-of-varchar-type

Comment: @JoelCochran: can you make this the answer? :)

Comment: @MichaelRys - Done :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can try VARCHAR(MAX), which will support up to 2GB, but the page size in SQL is still limited to 8,000 so I'm not sure if that will help or not. And Polybase is limited to 1MB per row. Here is another [useful SO entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57425069/azure-sql-data-warehouse-max-size-of-varchar-type)